# White-list certain binaries and scripts inside a noexec/nosuid mount?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, rhel, security

Just like the question. Is it possible to white-list certain executables from a noexec mounted FS?

for instance, mine looks like this:

```
/dev/vg/lv on /tmp type ext4 (rw,noexec,nosuid)
```

Comment: If by "whitelist" you mean allow them to be executed, the answer is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The mount options trump all. That's what they're for: to ensure that nothing ever gets executed directly from that filesystem.

To counter `noexec`, you can run most programs indirectly by invoking their launcher:

- If the program is a script (starting with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang%20(Unix))), invoke the interpreter and pass it the script as its first argument.
- If the program is a dynamically linked executable, invoke the dynamic loader (e.g. `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` or `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`) and pass it the binary as its first argument.

If you have a filesystem mounted with `noexec`, you can make a view of a directory where all files are executable with [bindfs](http://bindfs.org/). Bindfs doesn't allow setting permissions on a per-file basis however.

Of course you can make a copy of the file elsewhere and make that executable.

If the filesystem is mounted `nosuid`, there's no way to make the files setuid. That would break security. To make a setuid file, you need to have access to the owning user account. Making a copy and making that setuid, or remounting without the `nosuid` option, are the only solutions.

Comment: Yes, its a script (with shebang) that's called up from another location. What do you mean by "invoke the launcher and pass it the script"? I'd like to try this method out.

Comment: @user53029 I mean what I wrote in my answer: invoke the interpreter and pass it the script as its first argument.

Comment: are you saying call up the script from inside the same script?

Comment: @user53029 I mean, for a script that starts with `#!/bin/bash`, call `/bin/bash /mnt/dir/script`, for a script that starts with `#!/usr/bin/env perl`, call `/usr/bin/env perl /mnt/dir/script`, etc.